# Char array using pointers is not updating in C

Tags: c, pointers

apologies ahead of time as I am VERY new to C and pointers in general. I'm attempting to pass a variable declared in my main sub to another sub in order to have the user input information that will then update the variable value in the main sub. However I must be using pointers incorrectly as I have tried all I can think of but the variables in my main sub are not updating.

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Prototypes
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void GetUserInfo(char* pstrState)

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: main
// Abstract: This is where the program starts.
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void main()
{   
    //Variables
    char strState;

    //Getting User Info
    GetUserInfo(&strState);

    printf("STATE: %s", strState);
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: GetUserInfo
// Abstract: Prompts the user for info and validates the entries
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void GetUserInfo(char* pstrState))
{   
    //Variables
    int intChoice = 0;

    //Getting State by numeric selection - this loop will continue until a selection is made
    printf("STATE:\n");
    while (intChoice != 1 && intChoice != 2)
    {
        printf("Please enter a '1' for OHIO or '2' for KENTUCKY.\n");
        scanf("%d", &intChoice);
    }

    //Assigning state to variable
    if (intChoice == 1)
    {   
        //Building string and terminating
        pstrState = malloc(5);
        pstrState[0] = 'O';
        pstrState[1] = 'H';
        pstrState[2] = 'I';
        pstrState[3] = 'O';
        pstrState[4] = 0;
    }
    else if (intChoice == 2)
    {
        //Building string and terminating.
        pstrState = malloc(9);
        pstrState[0] = 'K';
        pstrState[1] = 'E';
        pstrState[2] = 'N';
        pstrState[3] = 'T';
        pstrState[4] = 'U';
        pstrState[5] = 'C';
        pstrState[6] = 'K';
        pstrState[7] = 'Y';
        pstrState[8] = 0;
    }
```

Comment: `void main()` not the error, wrong though.

Comment: Changes to `pstrState` inside the function (as in `pstrState = malloc(...)` ) are not visible to the caller. Changes to what `pstrState` points to would have been visible - but `GetUserInfo` makes no such changes. Besides, `char strState` only has space for a single character, ain't no way you can put a string into it.

Comment: All modern C++ compilers will give you a big fat warning message for a `printf` mismatch, between its `%s` and the actual parameter. This will the first big honking clue as to what the problem is, which should set of a chain of a mental thought process that will unravel all the other problems with the shown code. But I'm curious, which C++ textbook you are using that wastes time on C library functions, like `printf`? You should switch to a different C++ textbook that focuses on the actual C++ library, rather than the C library; and `std::string` instead of tossing `char *`s around.

Comment: Please chose between C and C++, they are different languages.

Comment: Before you work on a second function, you should make sure that your initial function is working. If you take out the call to `GetUserInfo`, your main function looks like `void main()
{   
    char strState;
    printf("STATE: %s", strState);
}`. Does this demonstrate a valid baseline? Well, it's tough to tell when `strState` is not initialized. So initialize `strState` to some value. Now does your main function demonstrate a valid baseline? I doubt it, due to other problems. I suggest you work on those problems before you add to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char strState;` declares a single `char`. You want `char* strState;` (pointer to char).

Change `GetUserInfo(char* pstrState);` to `GetUserInfo(char** pstrState);`. `pstrState` is now a pointer to a pointer!

Inside `GetUserInfo(char** pstrState);` you need to change `pstrState` to `*pstrState`.

Comment: But you really should consider using ``std::string`` if you can use C++. C-style strings are not trivial at all (and please get (and read) a good textbook!)

Comment: Thank you very much this was super helpful! Sometimes people just comment something along the lines of "you're wrong" without really explaining why. This is much appreciated!

Comment: I thank you for your feedback :-)